# nodemon failed to start due to some error

Tags: node.js

This error  comes when i run programme using global nodemon, but it fine when only i use node

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

without nodemon it works correctly but globally run gives error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to run `nodemon` in place of`node`. Looks like you're running `nodemon node server.js` instead run

```
nodemon server.js
```